# How can I concatenate two fields from a list using Java 8 and StringJoiner?

Tags: java, string, java-8

I have class:

```
public class Item {

   private String first;
   private String second;

   public Item(String first, String second) {
       this.first = first;
       this.second = second;
   }
}
```

And list of such objects:

```
List<Item> items = asList(new Item("One", "Two"), new Item("Three", "Four"));
```

My goal is to join list of elements in order to build following string:

```
One: Two; Three: Four;
```

I've tried to use StringJoiner, but it looks like it is designed to work with list of some simple types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
final String result = items.stream()
        .map(item -> String.format("%s: %s", item.first, item.second))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
```

As [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) mentioned in the comment below, last `;` will be missed using this construction. It can be added manually to the final String or you can simply try solution suggested by assylias.

Comment: You will miss the last `;`

Comment: You can use the prefix/suffix overload for that.

Answer (score 10):

You can map the item to a string that concatenates the fields and then join the items, separating them with a space:

```
String result = items.stream()
                     .map(it -> it.field1 + ": " + it.field2 + ";")
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

First step is to join `field1` and `field2`.

Second step is to join with `;`.

Note that this won't add a `;` at the end.

```
List<Item> items = asList(new Item("One", "Two"), new Item("Three", "Four"));

String joined = items.stream()
        // First step
        .map(it -> it.field1 + ": " + it.field2)
        // Second step
        .collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
```

## Somewhat more OO

Or better yet: move logic to join `field1` and `field2` to a dedicated method:

```
public static class Item {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public Item(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getField1And2() {
        return field1 + ": " + field2;
    }

}
```

And use that one in the stream.

```
String joined = items.stream()
        .map(Item::getField1And2)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
```